# Java intermitent peer not authenticated exception

Tags: java, ssl, vert.x

So I set up a JMeter test running against my vertx.io server and as the test executes a 'Peer not authenticated' exception gets thrown once in a while.

Searching through Google most people suggest that I disable trust certificates, but clearly this isn't the problem, because the JMeter client obviously connects and is able to to send request but once in a while the exception gets thrown. There are some other SSL exceptions that get thrown intermittently as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am trying to determine whether this is a jmeter issue or a site issue.  It only appears to occur under heavy load testing.

Comment: Not really. With HTTPClient 4.1 of jmeter it seems to do it less... But no concrete proof.

Comment: Drat.  Thanks anyway.